# How can I override a playbook var if it's set in host_vars in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

server1 is in the group *it_servers*, but I'd like to use `ansible_connection: local`. How can this be done if `ansible_connection` is defined in the playbook and the host_vars?

```
--
- hosts: it_servers
  vars:
    ansible_connection: aws_ssm
  roles:
    - nginx
    - mysql
```

#### My *host_vars/server1.yml* file

```
ansible_connection: local
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Q: *"**How to override playbook var if it's set in host_vars in Ansible?**"*

A: Take a look at [Variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). The precedence of *play vars* is 12. There are 10 more possibilities of how to override *play vars*, but none of them will let you selectively override a variable for a single host.

You'll have to delete the declaration of `ansible_connection: aws_ssm` from the playbook if you want to change it for a single host. The best place for the **group** declaration of the connection is **group_vars** (precedence 3-7) and the best place to override the group_vars for a single host is **host_vars** (precedence 8-10). For example

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[aws1]
server1 ansible_connection=local      # precedence 8.
server2
server3

[aws1:vars]
ansible_connection=aws_ssm            # precedence 3.
```

There are many combinations of *host_vars* and *group_vars* to achieve this scenario. But, if you set a variable at *play vars* (precedence 12) you can't override it for a single host anymore.

---

**Dynamic variable**

It's possible to declare the variable dynamically. For example

```yaml
ansible_connection: "{{ 'local'
                        if inventory_hostname == 'server1'
                        else
                        'aws_ssm' }}"
```

This would work at any precedence level. But, because of the lazy evaluation, it's very inefficient. The variable will be evaluated each time referenced.

---

**'Instantiate' the dynamic variable**

If you really need to use the dynamic variable 'instantiate' it to avoid repeated evaluation. What does it mean? For example, given the inventory (in YAML for better readability)

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  hosts:
    server1:
      ansible_host: localhost
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.8
    server2:
      ansible_host: 10.1.0.62
      ansible_user: admin
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.8
    server3:
      ansible_host: 10.1.0.63
      ansible_user: admin
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.8
  children:
    servers:
      hosts:
        server1:
        server2:
        server3:
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: servers
  vars:
    ansible_connection: "{{ 'local'
                            if inventory_hostname == 'server1'
                            else
                            'ssh' }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_connection') }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: ansible_connection
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [servers] *****************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************
ok: [server1]
ok: [server2]
ok: [server3]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [server1] => 
  msg: '[AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined]'

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [server1] => 
  ansible_connection: local
ok: [server2] => 
  ansible_connection: ssh
ok: [server3] => 
  ansible_connection: ssh
```

The connections work as expected, but the variable *ansible_connection* is not included in the *hostvars*. Use the module *set_fact* and 'instantiate' the variable, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ansible_connection: "{{ ansible_connection }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_connection') }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************
ok: [server1]
ok: [server2]
ok: [server3]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [server1] => 
  msg:
  - local
  - ssh
  - ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delegate_to:  localhost` for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible does apply variable precedence, and you might have a use for it. Here is the order of precedence from least to greatest (the last listed variables override all other variables):

command line values (for example, -u my_user, these are not variables)

role defaults (defined in role/defaults/main.yml) 1

inventory file or script group vars 2

inventory group_vars/all 3

playbook group_vars/all 3

inventory group_vars/* 3

playbook group_vars/* 3

inventory file or script host vars 2

inventory host_vars/* 3

playbook host_vars/* 3

host facts / cached set_facts 4

play vars

play vars_prompt

play vars_files

role vars (defined in role/vars/main.yml)

block vars (only for tasks in block)

task vars (only for the task)

include_vars

set_facts / registered vars

role (and include_role) params

include params

extra vars (for example, -e "user=my_user")(always win precedence)

This is better explained here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable